# Bootstrap CSS - navbar list wraps starting on a new line. How to make <ul> wrap starting on the current line?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to fix an issue where my `<ul>` list does not wrap / break correctly on small displays. I have my navbar show "Test Tools" *then* `<ul>`. However on small displays it will only show "Test Tools" on one line, then put the entire `<ul>` on the next line. Then the `<ul>` wraps onto another line below it (3 lines total).

## Current Behavior

```
LINE 0: "Test Tools"
LINE 1: <ul> line one
LINE 2: <ul> continues on third line
```

## Desired Behavior

```
LINE 0: "Test Tools" <ul> line one
LINE 1: <ul> continues on second line
```

## ISSUE

Here's what my navbar looks like at a good width (no wrapping):

[image]

When you resize your window to be smaller, the wrapping works not as expected. **It only shows "Test Tools" on one entire line by itself**:

[image]

Then you can use the scrollbar on the right to go down a line to see the button list:

[image]

**What I want**: I want "Test Tools" to show, then **as many buttons as possible should come next on the same line** (similar to the first image). Any buttons that don't fit should be shown on the next line (visible by using the scrollbar on the right).

## CODE

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ksissons/Leh7r53m/18/

```css
.toolsBar .navbar-default {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    overflow: overlay;
}

.toolsBar .navbar .nav {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    display: list-item;
    float: left;
}

.navbar .nav {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.toolsBar .navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0px 12px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#toolBarList {
    overflow: overlay;
}

.toolsBar .navbar-brand {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.toolsBar .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: white;
}

#toolsBar .navbar-default {
    background-color: #566b7f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid toolsBar" id="toolsBar">
 <div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <span class="navbar-brand">Test Tools</span>
  </div>
  <div>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="toolBarList">
                  <li>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">Test Readiness Status</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">Run Detective Tool</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a  class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">Go to Confluence</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">How to Update mp3 Files</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">Generate &amp; View Report</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">Show Configuration Variables</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">Edit Configuration Variables</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">Update Content Automatically</a>
                  </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you put your `.navbar-header` in the nav list?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid toolsBar" id="toolsBar">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="toolBarList" style="overflow: overlay;">
      <li>
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <span class="navbar-brand">Test Tools</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">Test Readiness Status</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">Run Detective Tool</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">Go to Confluence</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">How to Update mp3 Files</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">Generate &amp; View Report</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">Show Configuration Variables</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">Edit Configuration Variables</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle">Update Content Automatically</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't consider that! Works perfect, thank you! ^_^